# Is is possible to include views in a gem that the user can render as a partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

Say I am making gem "awesome_o" and it will make apps awesome. How could I package up some view partials so that the user can optionally use them in his/her app for eg:

```
<%= render :partial => '#{some_path_to_awesome_o}/list_of_awesome' %>
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 9):

As I understand it, if you create an `app/views` directory in the base of your gem, Rails adds that to the views load path. So, create your partial at `app/views/my_gem/my_partial.html.ext`, and then `render :partial => 'my_gem/my_partial'` should work as expected.

As far as usage goes, though, I'd like you to include a simple helper method, too, since it'd be far easier for me to use and would allow you to change exact implementation later on. Even if it just calls `render :partial` internally, it'd produce a smoother experience.

Comment: Cool, I'll give this a try and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Nor with Rails 4.2

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays you could use an engine: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you could also make generators to create the views in the rails app, this would allow the users to alter the views to suit their needs.

I guess it depends on exactly what you are doing.